# How to sort Android ListView when i click on LIstView header?

Tags: android, android-listview

Any one help me that how can get list of items in sorted order when i click on ListView header.

Thanks,
@nag.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the adapter using one of the numerous sorting algorithms and then

onClicking ListView header write the following lines

yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I'm having list of objects like List<Class> so how can i sort this list of objects means the entire row should be sorted when i click any header on list view.

Answer (score 0):

Create an arraylist and add all strings to that. And then sort using Collections.sort(arrayList). Now create a new adapter with sorted arraylist strings, and set this adapter to the list view.

Comment: you said about how to sort based on List<String> but i've collection of objects so how can i do this one?

Comment: in which base you have to sort, strings or integers. what type of objects you have.

Comment: i've class objects and i written code by using comparable to sort class objects and its sorted list after loading activity but i want to sort whenever i click on header of the list view so how can i do this one?